# How to group chat messages based on Calendar date and time just like WhatsApp?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a chat application, but I have a problem. If anyone can help, I want to show date and time on top of a group of messages like WhatsApp. For example we have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1GzE.jpg)

My messages RecyclerView adapter like that:

```
class SingleChatAdapter(private var context: Context, messageList: ArrayList<SingleChatData>?, senderRoom: String,
                        receiverRoom: String, private val incDecNum: (Boolean) -> Unit,
                        private val showChosenToolbar: (Boolean, Boolean) -> Unit):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder?>() {
    
    private var selectedShared = IsSelectedShared(context)
    private val sentNum = 1
    private val receivedNum = 2
    private val senderRoom: String
    private val receiverRoom: String
    private lateinit var messages: ArrayList<SingleChatData>
    private val itemsData: ArrayList<SelectedItemsData>?= null
    // Voice Player
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == sentNum){
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.sent_message_content, parent, false)
            SentMsgViewHolder(view)
        } else {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.received_message_content, parent, false)
            ReceivedMsgViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messages.size
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val newMsg = messages[position]
        return if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid == newMsg.senderId){
            sentNum
        } else {
            receivedNum
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //
    }

    inner class SentMsgViewHolder(itemView: View): ViewHolder(itemView){
        var binding = SentMessageContentBinding.bind(itemView)
        private var onItemClick: ((data: SingleChatData, weakImage: WeakReference<ImageView>) -> Unit)?= null
        var data: SingleChatData?= null
        init {
            onItemClick.let { onItemClick ->
                data?.let { data->
                    if (onItemClick != null) {
                        onItemClick(data, WeakReference(binding.sentImg))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inner class ReceivedMsgViewHolder(itemView: View): ViewHolder(itemView){
        var binding = ReceivedMessageContentBinding.bind(itemView)
        private var onItemClick: ((data: SingleChatData, weakImage: WeakReference<ImageView>) -> Unit)?= null
        var data: SingleChatData?= null
        init {
            onItemClick.let { onItemClick ->
                data?.let { data->
                    if (onItemClick != null) {
                        onItemClick(data, WeakReference(binding.receivedImg))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    init {
        if (messageList != null){
            this.messages = messageList
        }
        this.senderRoom = senderRoom
        this.receiverRoom = receiverRoom
    }
}
```

I tried too many times to find a solution, but I can't find the proper way.
If anyone can help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You already have two item types in your array.  Add a 3rd item type-  DateMarker.  Walk through your list of messages and insert date markers where appropriate. Then you can display it as a normal view type, and define its view any way you want.